# Display elements in a tree

Tags: jquery, dom, tree

I have some div like below:

```
<div id="header1-1" class="header1>header1</div>
<div id="header2-1" class="header2>header2</div>
<div id="header1-2" class="header1>header1</div>
<p>text</p>
<div id="header2-2" class="header2>header2</div>
<div id="header3-1" class="header3>header3</div>
```

I want to display a tree:

```
header1
  header 2
header1
    header2
         header3
```

I am having big troubles with this:

```
$( ".header"+i ).each(function() {
        $('.fr-placeholder').remove();
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).attr('id', 'header'+i+'-'+j);

        j++;
        headers.push(j);

        if(txt.length != 0){
            var divId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#outline').append('<li><a data-id="'+divId+'" >'+txt+'</a></li>' );
        }

    });

    for (var k = 1; k < headers.length; k++) {

        var l = k + 1;
        var siblings = $('#header'+i+'-'+k).nextUntil('#header'+i+'-'+l);

    }
```

I am trying to find all elements between 2 divs and populate my tree but this is wrong since between header 2 and header 2 is header 1 and Header 1 is suposused to be parent. Also i have other dom elements like text,  and I want tod isplay only headers. Does anywone suggests me another  way?

Comment: Can you amend the HTML structure? Using nested `ul` elements is a much more semantic (not to mention simple) method of achieving this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is difficult since I am using drag and drop elements. I have a button header which I drag and it generates the div. I have 3 butttons: heading1 heading 2 heading3 each one generates a div. How can I improve this?